# Check if time is between two times ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to check if the DateTime.now is between 2 particular date and times on Ruby on Rails.

I can't seem to figure it out

```
 def closed?
  (DateTime.now > DateTime.new(2018, 6, 28, 13, 00, 00)) && (DateTime.now < DateTime.new(2018, 6, 28, 14, 00, 00))
 end
```

Comment: Is what you've written not working? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: This looks like it should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: `DateTime.now` returns datetime in your timezone while `DateTime.new` will build it in timezone "+00:00". That might be the issue. Check their values.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use the [`between?(min, max)` function from `ActiveSupport`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F):

```ruby
def closed?
  DateTime.now.between?(DateTime.new(2018, 6, 28, 13, 00, 00), DateTime.new(2018, 6, 28, 14, 00, 00))
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about between?

Answer (score 12):

You can use cover? method for that

```
now = DateTime.now
start = DateTime.new(2018, 6, 28, 13, 00, 00)
stop =  DateTime.new(2018, 6, 28, 14, 00, 00)
p (start..stop).cover? now
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only compare time then you can simply do

```
Time.zone.now.between?(Time.zone.parse("12:00"), Time.zone.parse("18:00"))
```

Time zone is a important factor here.

Comment: And if the DateTime object in question is not today, you could do sth. like this: `Time.zone.parse(relevant_date.strftime("%H:%M")).between?(Time.zone.parse("12:00"), Time.zone.parse("18:00"))`